# Connection to secure web socket python server from reactjs client

Tags: python, reactjs, websocket

Trying to connect websocket python server from the reactjs client.

SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.

Web socket python server

```
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
localhost_pem = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("localhost.pem")
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(localhost_pem)

start_server = websockets.serve(
    asl_video, "0.0.0.0", 8766, ssl=ssl_context, ping_interval=30, ping_timeout=30, max_size=None
)
```

Code in reactjs application

```
var webSocket =  new W3CWebSocket('wss://10.12.5.112:8766');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the following line (line number 62) in the file node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js

`protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws',`
which was previously 
`protocol: 'ws',`

It resolved the error 
SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.

Thanks,